# SELECT Without wildcard returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql

For some reason my SELECT query with an AND clause is exhibiting some odd behaviour. It returns zero rows, when I know for a fact that there are matches. If I remove either of the clauses, it works. Or, the strangest part, if I add a wildcard to the end of the string to match, it returns the expected results. Even though there doesn't appear to be any extra bytes at the end of the column data.

A demonstration:

```
SELECT HEX(type),
       type,
       category 
  FROM cats 
 WHERE `category` = 10 AND 
       `type` LIKE "Furry";

Empty set (0.07 sec)
```

but

```
SELECT HEX(type),type,category FROM cats WHERE `type` LIKE "Furry";
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| HEX(type)                        | type                   | category |
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| 4675727279                       | Furry                  |       10 |
...
```

And

```
SELECT HEX(type),type,category FROM cats WHERE `category`=10 AND `type` LIKE "Furry%";
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| HEX(type)                        | type                   | category |
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| 4675727279                       | Furry                  |       10 |
...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check the length of the `type` column's value. There may be other characters there. `SELECT LENGTH(type) WHERE type LIKE 'Furry%'`

Comment: MySQL will ignore trailing whitespace with an equality `=` operator, but not with `LIKE`.  Although `SELECT HEX('Furry')` does return `4675727279`...

Comment: LENGTH does return 5. Also, matching a single character at the end (_), returns nothing.